# Can other method behave as AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#, delegates, asynccallback, iasyncresult

I am implementing vivox in unity and I came across a situation in the tutorial where the guy has done something with `AsyncCallback` delegate that I want to confirm.

```
using UnityEngine;
using VivoxUnity;
using System;

public class VivoxLearn : MonoBehaviour
{
    VivoxUnity.Client client;
    ILoginSession loginSession;

private string issuer="";
private string tokenKey = "";
private string domain = "";
private Uri server=new Uri("");
private TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(90);
private AsyncCallback loginCallback;              //check-1

private void Awake()
{
    client = new Client();
    client.Uninitialize();
    client.Initialize();
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
void Start()
{
    loginCallback = new AsyncCallback(Login_Result);      //check-2
}
public void Login(string username)
{
    AccountId accountId = new AccountId(issuer, username, domain);
    loginSession.BeginLogin(server, loginSession.GetLoginToken(tokenKey, timespan), loginCallback);//check-3
}

private void Login_Result(IAsyncResult ar)               //check-4
{
    try
    {
        loginSession.EndLogin(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}
}
```

In line check-3, instead of creating `AsyncCallback` delegate(check-1) and passing `Login_Result` (check-4) method to delegate(check-2), what if I directly pass `Login_Result` as the last argument in line (check-3)? Is that a legit and allowed way? If yes, then please explain a bit that why it is allowed to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr

**Yes**, as long as it has the same signature

- returns `void`
- takes `IAsyncResult` as only parameter

---

-> [`AsyncCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.asynccallback)

It is basically simply

```
public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
```

which basically equals using [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action-1)

```
Action<IAsyncResult>
```

except that using [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates) you can give the parameters some meaningful names and XML documentation comment tags.

Both are basically just [signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-signatures) templates (very carefully said it is a little bit like interfaces and types). You can assign any method implementing the correct signature to them.

---

If you don't intend to somewhere store that delegate (like in your example in a field) then - as with any other value - it doesn't matter at all if you pass the callback method directly or via the delegate definition (see [How to declare, instantiated and use a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-declare-instantiate-and-use-a-delegate))

```
loginCallback = new AsyncCallback(Login_Result);
```

is just the older way to write it. You can also simply do

```
loginCallback = Login_Result;
```

and then it makes no difference if you first store this in a field or directly pass it to the method.

So you can also directly do

```
loginSession.BeginLogin(server, loginSession.GetLoginToken(tokenKey, timespan), new AsyncCallback(Login_Result);
```

or as said simply

```
loginSession.BeginLogin(server, loginSession.GetLoginToken(tokenKey, timespan), Login_Result);
```